# Facing issue with Binding Library for iOS for magtek and getting errors when build the application after adding reference of this library

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, mono, cocoa-bindings

I am using magtek device in my application, So, I have made a DLL or Binding Library with the iOS SDK of magtek device, But after making DLL, when I am using this in my application So, my application given error, that are below:

```
/Users/chetu/Desktop/Tusshar/CurrentApp/PsnAmcApp/App12/App12.iOS/clang: Error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) (PaymentServiceNetwork.iOS)

/Users/chetu/Desktop/Tusshar/CurrentApp/PsnAmcApp/App12/App12.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: MTSCRA. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_MTSCRA' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. (MT5211) (PaymentServiceNetwork.iOS)

/Users/chetu/Desktop/Tusshar/CurrentApp/PsnAmcApp/App12/App12.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT5201: Native linking failed. Please review the build log and the user flags provided to gcc: -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker

/Users/chetu/Desktop/Tusshar/CurrentApp/PsnAmcApp/App12/App12.iOS/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone8.1-9.3/Entitlements.xcent (MT5201) (PaymentServiceNetwork.iOS)

/Users/chetu/Desktop/Tusshar/CurrentApp/PsnAmcApp/App12/App12.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. (MT5202) (PaymentServiceNetwork.iOS)
```

And, for magtek sdk is available on below link:
http://www.magtek.com/support/software/downloads/sw/99510111.zip

Using this command I have created dll which will use in visual studio IOS instance.

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch -unsafe --outdir=tmp -out:MagTek.iDynamo.dll MagTek.iDynamo.cs enums.cs -x=AssemblyInfo.cs --link-with=libMTSCRA.a,libMTSCRA.a
```

when I am giving reference of the same dll I am getting that issue.

And, I am using latest version of Visual studio on mac machine.

So, Please help me with this issue to resolve.

Comment: How do you make the dll? Have you read this: [Binding iOS Libraries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/)?

Comment: Yes, I have read this:  Binding iOS Libraries and also follow the same steps in that link provided.

Comment: But still I am getting same issue. So, Can you please check where I am wrong in my Code or application